# Automapper does not bind generic list

Tags: c#, json, automapper

I'm using Automapper to mapped unknown(Unknown property) JSON object with know object(Model)In c# (using profiles) but could not bind getting list empty.

**Model**

```
public class Student
        {
                public string Name {get;set;}
                public string Age{get;set;}
                  public string RoleId{get;set;}

        }
```

**JSON**

```
var jsonText = @"
                       [ {
                            ""Code"" : ""Class786"",
                            ""HighLevelClassOfBusinessCode"" :3
                        },

                        {
                            ""Code"" : ""Class789"",
                            ""HighLevelClassOfBusinessCode"" :79
                        }
                        ]

                ";
```

**AUTOMAPPER:**

```
      // its working when loop through list mapped one by one but i need list
    public List<Student> GetNewList<Student>(JArray JsonData)
    {

        List<Student> dto = new List<Student>();
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<JArray, List<Student>>();
            cfg.AddProfile<Student>();
        });
        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

        List<Student> newData = mapper.Map<List<Student>>(JsonData);
       //List newData which are getting is empty 

        // if i used json object in loop then working fine
        //foreach (var item in JsonData)
        //{
        //    T newData= mapper.Map<T>(item);
        //    dto.Add(newData);
        //}
        return dto;
    }
```

**Profile: which are created for mapping rule**

```
public class Student: Profile
        {
            public Student()
            {
                CreateMap<JObject, Student>()
                    .ForMember("Name", cfg => { cfg.MapFrom(jo => jo["Code"]); })
                    .ForMember("Age", cfg => { cfg.MapFrom(jo => jo["Code"]); })
                    .ForMember("RoleId", cfg => { cfg.MapFrom(jo => jo["HighLevelClassOfBusinessCode"]); });
            }

        }
```

Comment: Have you tried deserializing?

Comment: Type will b dynamic ..will get only json object and then will do perform mapping base on json only no model